# phrasing union and intersection of graphs (cycles)?

Tags: graph-theory

If I am having cycle graphs for example $G_1, G_2, G_3$. then how can I phrase **union** and **intersection** of **adjoining graphs** (i.e. having at least one common node with other) in mathematical notations.

For example if I want to do $G_1 \cup G_2$ or $G_2 \cup G_3$ and $G1 \cap G_2$ or $G_2 \cap G_3$.

So, I want to phrase these intersection and union with **common variables** with **mathematical notations** (except $G_1, G_2, G_3$).

Here, is my example figure:

[image]

Comment: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @A.P: its look fine now. thanks